# Spring RestTemplate on Jelastic - Connection Refused when requesting external rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I have application that need to call Rest service, to do authentication process. The service and my application are in a same server. I used Spring RestTemplate to call it. When it tested in localhost, it works perfectly. But when I deploy it to the cloud server (in this case, Jelastic) I get this error:

```
I/O error on GET request for "[my_rest_service_address]":Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

All the code is follow this doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html. Only the url that changed to my rest url.

Is it happened because jelastic server blocked outbound request? But, both the service and my application are in the same server, why it still blocked?

Please explain to me, what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: You must provide the code to which ip you are connecting. Seems right here that the address is "[rest_service_address]" ? that is not an ip address / valid url

Comment: Of course it isn't the real address. I connect to jelastic cloud server.

Answer (score 0):

The http 401 code means that the user that made the request is not authenticated. It can be the user of your webapp or the user used for the rest call.

It can for example that different credentials are used in prod and test, different security schemes in each environment, etc.

Comment: Actually the request is to retrieve token,from the Rest Service, and it happened in CustomAuthenticationProvider of Spring Security. So, I think 401 Code produced because the request failed in authentication process of Spring Security context. So I think, is it happened because jelastic server blocked the outbound request? But, it actually the token service and my application are in the same server. Why it still blocked?

Comment: Do you use username/password or another mechanism? In the former scenario, try to do wget -uusername:password http://<rest_service_ip>/... and check if it works.